# Deserialize JSON USGS Earthquake Catalog API

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I've recently completed the Treehouse online course "C# Streams and Data Processing" and one of the lessons in the course showed how to use Webclient to query an API and parse the data returned. The example shown used a Microsoft Bing API to retrieve data about soccer players, but I'm trying to create my own project using a different API, which is the USGS Earthquake Catalog. It shows data about recent earthquakes:
[USGS Earthquake Catalog](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/)

I've got the Webclient working and am getting the return data. I've created a new class for the data and have pasted it as JSON, but I'm not sure why I can't access the properties in my code?
what I'd like to be able to do is run a loop to iterate through the data and show the magnitude, location and time.

```
namespace Earthquakes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetEarthquakes();
        }

        public static void GetEarthquakes()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            byte[] earthquakeBytes = webClient.DownloadData("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2020-08-01&endtime=2020-08-02");
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(earthquakeBytes))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                string jsonString = "";
                var earthquake = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Earthquakes>(jsonString);
                Console.WriteLine(earthquake.Metadata.title);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
namespace Earthquakes
{

    public class Metadata
    {
        public long Generated { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public string api { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        [JsonProperty("mag")]
        public double Magnitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("place")]
        public string Place { get; set; }
        public object Time { get; set; }
        public object Updated { get; set; }
        public object Tz { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }
        public int? Felt { get; set; }
        public double? Cdi { get; set; }
        public double? Mmi { get; set; }
        public string Alert { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int Tsunami { get; set; }
        public int Sig { get; set; }
        public string Net { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Ids { get; set; }
        public string Sources { get; set; }
        public string Types { get; set; }
        public int? Nst { get; set; }
        public double? Dmin { get; set; }
        public double Rms { get; set; }
        public double? Gap { get; set; }
        public string MagType { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feature
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Earthquakes
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
        public List<double> Bbox { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to deserialize to a namespace `Earthquakes`, this is wrong. why are you making the jsonString to empty `string jsonString = "";`

Comment: Your jsonsString is empty.....

Comment: Please consider using `HttpClient` over the ancient `WebClient`.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. It seems the main problem in your code is that you are completely ignoring the data you are downloading and instead you are deserializing an empty string.  You can actually simplify your code quite a bit by using the `DownloadString` method instead of `DownloadData`.  Then you can fetch the JSON and deserialize it in just a couple lines of code:

   ```
   webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2020-08-01&endtime=2020-08-02");
   var quakes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Earthquakes>(json);
   ```
2. You don't actually need to include properties for everything in the JSON if you are only interested in a few things.  If you only want magnitude, place and time, then your model classes could be as simple as this:

   ```
   class Earthquakes
   {
       public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
   }

   class Feature
   {
       public Properties Properties { get; set; }
   }

   class Properties
   {
       [JsonProperty("mag")]
       public decimal Magnitude { get; set; }

       public string Place { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("time")]
       public long TimeMs { get; set; }

       public DateTime Time => new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(TimeMs);
   }
   ```

   Also notice that I have added a convenience method to convert the `time` value from the JSON into a readable date.
3. You have a namespace called `Earthquakes` and a class `Earthquakes` within it.  While this is legal in C#, it makes the code harder to understand.  I would recommend renaming one or the other so they are not the same.  For example, you could rename the namespace `EarthquakeDemo` or rename the class `EarthquakeInfo`.  Up to you of course.  Also, I would recommend making the `GetEarthquakes()` method return the earthquakes it fetches instead of being a void method.  Then you can separate the fetch logic from the display logic.

Here is a working demo with the above changes applied and display logic added: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uRg48y

Comment: thank you. So DownloadData returns a byte array, what's the advantage or disadvantage of using this versus DownloadString?

Comment: JSON data is inherently string data, so using `DownloadString` is more appropriate.  (Be sure to set the `Encoding` property on the `WebClient` first though.)  `DownloadData` is mainly intended for binary data like images or videos.  If you use `DownloadData` for text then you need to do the extra work to decode the byte array into a string yourself before you can deserialize it.  Note that if you have very large amounts of data to process then using streams may be a better way to go.  In that case, you would use `OpenRead` along with a `StreamReader` instead of either of these methods.